# Add parent filter to category collection

Tags: category, magento-1, collection, filter

Is the more native way of adding parent filter on a category collection other than a direct `where` showcased below?

```
/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection $categoryCollection */
$categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection');
$categoryCollection->getSelect()->where('e.parent_id = ' . $parentId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound too easy, but isn't it same as :)

```
$categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection');
$categoryCollection->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', $parentId);
```

Comment: @TimBezhashvyly Yes, of course :)

Comment: @TimBezhashvyly I also checked if something changed from 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3.x  ... but no, this should work with 1.9.2 too.